# Deeplinlks not working even after hosting assets.json file in my server in marshmallow and Above os

Tags: android, deep-linking

Getting this error in initial launch.
[image]

Comment: Test it with this tool: https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed once the link is hosted with SSL